# Custom Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, int, lampp

Let's say i create this table

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
id int(10),
dep int(1),
name varchar(45),
email varchar(45),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (dep) REFERENCES department(id)
);
```

But i don't want the "id" to be a random number, i want it to be a specific 10 number integer for each entry, for example the first entry's id should be specifically "3012302509"

So i use insert:

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (3012302509, 1, 'Arnar Arnarsson', 'arni@yorozuya.is');
```

But the ID will turn into some other number than what i wrote like "1510312374" even if i wrote what i did above, how can i make it accept the number i enter in the insert command as the id?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: What database system? What you've shown looks correct for most systems.

Comment: is the `id` column an auto generated/identity column?

Comment: Lampp(xampp on linux) but it may be outdated

Comment: does `int` have  a size specifier?

Comment: Are you aware that there is no difference in the values that `int(10)` and `int(1)` can store? The number does *not* limit the digits you can put into that column. It's merely a hint for client applications on how wide you expect them to display the content.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an value overflow. There is possibly a maximum value for INT like in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/numeric-types.html). It depends on your database system, which type is more appropriate for your values. In MySQL you could e.g. use BIGINT or NUMERIC instead

Comment: When i try bigint(10) or numeric(10) i get:

SQL query:

INSERT INTO starfsmadur
VALUES ( 3012302509, 1,  'Arnar Arnarsson',  'arni@yorozuya.is' ) ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bokhald`.`starfsmadur`, CONSTRAINT `starfsmadur_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`deildnr`) REFERENCES `deild` (`nr`))

Comment: That's because you have changed datatype for id column in staff table but not in parent table dep.

Comment: Allright i fixed that and changed them all ints to numerics (also tried bigint) now it works only for some rows, but not all, 3 out of my 10 rows have a random number while the others have the one i entered.

Answer (score 0):

Change column data type to numeric(10,0).